# How to know number of dimensions in C function called by nquad?

Tags: python, c, scipy

Scipy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html#scipy.integrate.nquad) for nquad states that a c function used for integration is of the form

```
f(int n, double args[n])
where n is the number of extra parameters and args is an array of doubles of the additional parameters.
```

So how is the c function supposed to know how many dimensions are being integrated in order to use correct number of args?

If I modify the c function used in general [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#faster-integration-using-ctypes) to:

```
#include "stdio.h"
double f(int n, double args[]) {
    (void)args;
    printf("%i\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

compile with

```
gcc -fPIC -shared func.c -o func.so
```

and run this python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes
from scipy.integrate import nquad
lib = ctypes.CDLL('func.so')
func = lib.f
func.restype = ctypes.c_double
func.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_double)
print(nquad(func, [[0, 1]]))
```

I get a value between 32764 and 32767 for n on 64bit fedora 25 while on a 32 bit fedora 25 I get 0. In above link the c function does not check the value of n but uses args[0]...args[2] so is there no way to know how many dimensions are being integrated?

Calling nquad with:

```
print(nquad(func, [[0, 1]], args = [1,2,3]))
```

instead does not change what is printed on 64 bit system even though n should be different. I'm using

```
gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)
Python 3.5.2
scipy 0.18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the documentation (your first link). I think what they say is, that instead of calling `func(x0, x1, ..., xn, t0, t1, ..., tm)`, they "condense all parameters into a count and an array in `f(int n, double args[n])`.

Note that both pushing all the variables onto the stack, and getting them from the stack are costly operations when performed often and that can be avoided in this manner.

Comment: The problem is that according to their documentation, and my testing, n only tells the number of additional parameters and not the number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in a scipy issue on github: n is the length of double args[] which includes the coordinates where the function should be evaluated and any additional parameters given to nquad and passed on to the c function.